# iOS safari, slow rendering issues with video and scale

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, html5-video, scale

In `iOS5`, I would like to scale a `div` so its size is proportional to the view port. When this `div` contains a `video` element and the zoom level is too high, the rendering is **very slow**.

The scaling is done like this:

```
   var scaleFactor = window.innerWidth / $("#videoContainer").width();
    $("#videoContainer").css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scaleFactor * 0.9 + ')',
        '-webkit-transform-origin': '0 0'
    });
```

[To reproduce click here.](http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/yhRNu/show) Then on your `iOS` device, press the `Show` button. Notice that the rendering isn't smooth.

[The complete jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/yhRNu/)

A few remarks:

1. The bug reproduces only on iOS device (iPad/iPhone) but not on the desktop
2. If the `initial-scale` is set to `1.0`, the bug doesn't occur
3. If the video element is removed, the bug doesn't occur
4. The bug reproduces on `iOS6`
5. I have tried to trigger hw acceleration by adding this css ruleset to div and video `{
           transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
           -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
       }`. But it didn't help
6. I have tried to remove the image and to replace it with a yellow background but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into the details of this specific case, you might want to try adding the following rulesets, which trigger hardware acceleration on iOS:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: I have added this css ruleset to `div` and `video` but it didn't help (look at: http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/yhRNu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using scale3d() instead of scale() as in the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/yhRNu/26/

Have also made a few tweaks to your code, moving the setup outside of the click handlers and using 'touchend' instead of 'click' if browser supports touch.

I only have access to the iPad simulator but the above change seems to improve performance, I would also look at the test image you're using as it is over 1024x768 which is reported to cause performance issues on iOS webkit, see article here (2/3 way down - section on avoiding repaints): http://joehewitt.com/2011/10/05/fast-animation-with-ios-webkit

Comment: I have replaced the image by a yellow background http://jsfiddle.net/yhRNu/29/. But still the yellow div flickers and I don't see a difference between `scale3d` and `scale`.